# Multiple processes driving an array of records

Tags: arrays, vhdl, record, multiprocess, synthesis

The following code showcases an array of records. The particularity is that for each element of the array, the field `AR` is driven by the process `process_AR` while the field `R` is driven by the process `process_R`.

```
library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use     ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity test_entity is
end entity;

architecture RTL of test_entity is

    -- Try with std_ulogic_vector or std_logic_vector
    subtype slv is std_logic_vector;
    subtype stdl is slv'element;

    type AR_record_t is record
        valid : stdl;
        addr : slv(15 downto 0);
    end record;

    type R_record_t is record
        ready : stdl;
        data : slv(31 downto 0);
    end record;

    type axil_record_t is record
        AR : AR_record_t;
        R  : R_record_t;
    end record;

    type array_of_axil_record_t is array(natural range <>) of axil_record_t;
    signal axil_read_channel : array_of_axil_record_t(0 to 1);

begin

    -- Process only deal with the AR channel
    process_AR : process
    begin
        wait for 20 ps;
        axil_read_channel(0).AR <= (valid => '1', addr => X"CAFE");
        axil_read_channel(1).AR <= (valid => '0', addr => X"DEAD");
    end process;

    -- Process only deal with the R channel
    process_R : process
    begin
        wait for 20 ps;
        axil_read_channel(0).R <= (ready => '0', data => X"12345678");
        axil_read_channel(1).R <= (ready => '1', data => X"89ABCDEF");
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This code works as (I) expected.
[image: Waveform, first code]
However, change the process_AR by the following (using a `for loop` now):

```
-- Process only deal with the AR channel
process_AR : process
begin
    wait for 20 ps;
    for i in axil_read_channel'range loop
        axil_read_channel(i).AR <= (valid => '1', addr => X"CAFE");
    end loop;
end process;
```

When using non-resolved types (std_ulogic and std_ulogic_vector), this new code fails:

> (vsim-3344) Signal "/test_entity/axil_read_channel(0).R.ready" has multiple drivers but is not a resolved signal.

I guess the `for loop` does not work because the it is sort of a 'dynamical' assignment and therefore `axil_read_channel` is considered instead of `axil_read_channel(i)` ?
On the other hand, the first version of the code (with hard coded '0' and '1') uses sort of 'static' assignment and therefore considers the two elements `axil_read_channel(0)` and `axil_read_channel(1)` as two signals and not element of an array ?

When using resolved types (std_logic and std_logic_vector):
[image: Waveform, second code, when using non-resolved types (std_logic and std_logic_vector)]

What is the reason behind the difference of behavior between the first code and second code ?

Is there a work around not involving for-generate (not applicable to my current design) for synthesis ?

Comment: You have the types the wrong way around. `std_ulogic` is an unresolved type, and `std_logic` is a `resolved` version of `std_ulogic`, hence it is allowed multiple drivers.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers
"Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of *drivers* for certain scalar signals. There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement. Each such signal assignment statement is said to be *associated* with that driver. ..."

Comment: 14.6 Dynamic elaboration "There are three particular instances in which elaboration occurs dynamically during simulation. These are as follows:
a) Execution of a loop statement with a for iteration scheme involves the elaboration of the loop parameter specification prior to the execution of the statements enclosed by the loop (see 10.10). This elaboration creates the loop parameter and evaluates the discrete range. ..."

Comment: 8. Names 8.1 General "A *static signal* name is a static name that denotes a signal. The *longest static prefix* of a signal name is the name itself, if the name is a static signal name; otherwise, it is the longest prefix of the name that is a static signal name. ...".

Comment: This question doesn't depend on -2008. There are no expanded definitions for static in play here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `loop` in a process to drive a signal of a composite type (array or record), the elaboration cannot determine which specific objects require a driver at elaboration time, hence it has to assume all objects within the composite type require a driver. This then creates a driver for the entire array/record, rather than each element that would have occured without the loop.

This is what is causing your error when you use resolved/unresolved types. The errors occurs with the unresolved types `std_ulogic(_vector)` because they are not allowed multiple drivers. The resolved types `std_logic(_vector)` are allowed multiple drivers and all of the elements undriven by you will have `'U'` driven on them.

Comment: *Is there a work around not involving for-generate (not applicable to my current design) for synthesis ?* As you show originally, as an example `axil_read_channel(0).AR` is a longest static prefix and using such works. Note IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) 8.8.1 Wait statement wherein a wait statement timeout clause is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing your question, is there a work around.   Probably.  Do your tools support VHDL-2008 aggregates with unconstrained elements?   If yes, the following may work (have not tried it):

```
-- continuing from your above declarations:

type array_of_AR_record_t is array(natural range <>) of AR_record_t;
type array_of_R_record_t is array(natural range <>) of R_record_t;

type axil_record_t is record
    AR : array_of_AR_record_t;
    R  : array_of_AR_record_t;
end record;

signal axil_read_channel : axil_record_t (AR(0 to 1), R(0 to 1)) ;

. . . 

-- Process only deal with the AR channel
process_AR : process
begin
    wait for 20 ps;
    for i in axil_read_channel.AR'range loop
        axil_read_channel.AR(i) <= (valid => '1', addr => X"CAFE");
    end loop;
end process;
```

We are looking at language changes in the next revision that could help simplify the declarations.   See:  https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues/81

Comment: This actually works, I had something similar before switching to the code shown in the issue.

Comment: I am not sure how the issue you mentioned is related to the problem. I have started to look at other issues to see if there are any more related. From a user perspective, I find quite "problematic" that the loop has a different behavior compare to the "non-loop" code. Do you think this should be addressed in the IEEE P1076 WG (if not already done) ?

Comment: First, the objection I could see to the code I wrote is that it has 0 to 1 twice.   This can be addressed with discriminants as shown in issue 81.

Comment: Second, the issue you are running into is called the longest static prefix.   It has been well known and complained about for some time.   I think if it could have been fixed it would have been fixed prior to this point.   Hard to say though, maybe compilers are alot better now.

Comment: @dalex78   So you want something like this addressed:  https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues/275.   See the notes section.